# How to stop a specific script in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Is there a code to stop a specific script? I've seen a way that allows you to end *all* scripts using taskkill.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "taskkill /f /im Cscript.exe", , True 
WshShell.Run "taskkill /f /im wscript.exe", , True
```

I simply want to end one specific script that is sleeping in a wscript.sleep not every script that is running at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. You need to preserve the ProcessId of the process you want to kill. Below code opens a notepad and kills it. This example shows you how to capture the ProcessId of the script when it was started and then kill it.

```
Private Sub KillTest()
  Dim killCmd
  Dim pid

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set EngineRun = WshShell.Exec("notepad")
  pid = EngineRun.ProcessID

  killCmd = "taskkill /pid " & CStr(pid)
  Set EngineRun = WshShell.Exec(killCmd)
  Set EngineRun = Nothing
  Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in VBScript; what does ProcessId mean? Is that the specific code I'm wanting to end?

Comment: The ProcessID or PID is the unique identifier the operating system assigns  to a running process.  Mukul's code should be identical to yours except you would be `Set`ting `EngineRun` to the return value of executing your script.  You would also need additional logic to determine when the correct time to kill it would be.

Comment: So what is the return value of executing my script? Also, would the CreateObject part be necessary for my script?